# How to calculate Latitude and Longitude of a point by distance and direction from another point

Tags: android, position, mapping, here-api

I'm looking to calculate the latitude and longitude of where to place a marker that is a specific distance and direction from a known position's latitude and longitude. This is for an Android app (in Java) using the HERE mapping API.

Comment: I have found a solution at [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10119479/calculating-lat-and-long-from-bearing-and-distance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10119479/calculating-lat-and-long-from-bearing-and-distance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our Android Mobile SDK (Java) currently supports calculating distance between two geocoordinates (lat, lon) via the `distanceTo` method of the `Geocoordinate` class.

https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/api_reference_java/index.html

The method you are requesting is currently not provided. However, our JavaScript SDK provides a `walk` method of the `H.geo.Point` class. This method returns the destination point, based on the given distance and bearing relative to the current point.

https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics_api/h-geo-point.html#h-geo-point__walk

The algorithm is based on the **Haversine** formula and so you can also use the formula to calculate the target point yourself.

Comment: Thank you, HERE Developer Support, a bit odd that you have the capability in the Javascript SDK but not the Android (Java) one. However I have found a solution (see above).